# Differences in memory management with these 2 function calls?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, c++11

Assuming `ptr` is a pointer to an object of type `T1` and `inst` is an instance of type `T2`:

```
T1* ptr(new T1);
T2 inst;
```

I design the methods of `T1` and `T2` accordingly, meaning that in `T1` I pretty much have only `void` functions that will operate on the `this` object and inside `T2` I will have methods that will access the actual members.
So I finally make 2 calls like so:

```
ptr->doSomething();
inst.doSomething();
```

Considering these 2 main differences ( pointers vs instance and the actual call `->` vs `.` ) and maybe the use of the `this` vs `member values`, in a multithreaded and high performing environment, the memory model imposed on `ptr` and `inst` is the same? What about the cost of context switching, stack creation/allocation, access to a value and so on?

**EDIT:**

it's strange how no one is mentioning allocators as a new player that can change the game for an allocation or the locality.

I would like to focus this on the memory model, on how things are working inside the hardware ( mainly x86 and ARM ).

Comment: Note that both use `this` internally, either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Note: your second "instance" *isn't*; it is a function declaration for a function called `inst` returning an object by-value of type `T2` and taking no parameters. I think you meant `T2 inst;`

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with multithreading, but if you want some idea of what that generates, write some code, and generate the asm and see if they are the same and if not you may figure some of it out.  Or you could come back and post the example code

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum I would like to focus on what is the price and how different it is this price in this 2 cases, the multithreaded environment is just an example of an high-performance environment where I need to consider all the checks and balances.

Comment: So there seems to be two things you are changing - 1. heap vs stack allocation 2. use of void functions - can you give an example of how the member functions of T1 and T2 will differ - if not than you can use T1 for both cases and talk about heap vs stack

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum not only that, the fact that I'm trying to focus on the memory model/management it's not a coincidence, for example the comment from juanchopanza makes me suspicious about the fact that there is some cost about pointer aliasing hidden somewhere and in the ( explicit? ) pointer case I can potentially gain something with a `const`

Comment: Are you asking: `What is the difference between calling member functions via a pointer vs calling them via an object instance`? That's the only meaningful part I could see in your question.

Comment: @kfsone more like " How I can write code that works best with the `branch prediction` transistors inside my CPU ? "

Comment: The question, as posted, is about calling effects - there aren't any. More important are the location and lifetime of the object and the cost of allocating a heap object vs the cheapness of pushing X bytes onto the stack.

Comment: you know that cache hits and branch prediction are two different things and since you don't have any branches in your examples, i'm wondering if you are just using performance buzzwords to make it sound important.   Please stick to your question, and clarify it

Comment: @user2485710 If that's the case, you need to edit your question again, especially the subject line. Also, the first answer you got, from Andrei, touches on the stack vs heap issue.

Comment: The two items in your question title are unrelated, the method of memory allocation makes no significant difference to the way the function is called, as kfsone demonstrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your question was simply this: What's the difference between calling "ptr->something()" and "instance.something()?"

From the perspective of function "something", absolutely nothing.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void Bar(int i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Foo concrete;
    Foo* dynamic = new Foo;

    concrete.Bar(1);
    dynamic->Bar(2);

    delete dynamic;
}
```

The compiler only emits one instance of Foo::Bar() which has to handle both cases, so there *can't* be any difference.

The only changes, if any, are at the call site. When invoking `dynamic->Bar()` the compiler will emit code equivalent to `this = dynamic; call Foo0Bar` to transfer the value of "dynamic" directly into wherever "this" is held (register/address). In the case of `concrete.Bar`, concrete will be on the stack, so it will emit slightly different code to load a stack offset into the same register/memory location and make the call. The function itself will have no way to tell.

---- EDIT ----

Here's the assembly from "g++ -Wall -o test.exe -O1 test.cpp && objdump -lsD test.exe | c++filt" with the above code, focusing on main:

```
main():
  400890:       53                      push   %rbx
  400891:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  400895:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40089a:       e8 f1 fe ff ff          callq  400790 <operator new(unsigned long)@plt>
  40089f:       48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
  4008a2:       be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
  4008a7:       48 8d 7c 24 0f          lea    0xf(%rsp),%rdi
  4008ac:       e8 47 00 00 00          callq  4008f8 <Foo::Bar(int)>
  4008b1:       be 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%esi
  4008b6:       48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
  4008b9:       e8 3a 00 00 00          callq  4008f8 <Foo::Bar(int)>
  4008be:       48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
  4008c1:       e8 6a fe ff ff          callq  400730 <operator delete(void*)@plt>
  4008c6:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4008cb:       48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
  4008cf:       5b                      pop    %rbx
  4008d0:       c3                      retq
```

Our member function calls are here:

concrete.Bar(1)

```
4008a2:       be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
4008a7:       48 8d 7c 24 0f          lea    0xf(%rsp),%rdi
4008ac:       e8 47 00 00 00          callq  4008f8 <Foo::Bar(int)>
```

dynamic->Bar(2)

```
4008b1:       be 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%esi
4008b6:       48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
4008b9:       e8 3a 00 00 00          callq  4008f8 <Foo::Bar(int)>
```

Clearly "rdi" is being used to hold "this", and the first uses a stack-relative address (since `concrete` is on the stack) and the second simply copies the value of "rbx", which has the return value from "new" earlier on (`mov %rax,%rbx` after the call to new)

---- EDIT 2 ----

Beyond the function call itself, speaking to the actual operations that have to occur constructing, tearing down and accessing-values-within objects, the stack is generally faster.

```
{
    Foo concrete;
    foo.Bar(1);
}
```

generally takes less cycles than

```
Foo* dynamic = new Foo;
dynamic->Bar(1);
delete dynamic;
```

because the second variant has to allocate memory and, in general, memory allocators are slow (they typically have some kind of lock in them to manage a shared memory pool). Also, the memory allocated for this may be cache-cold (although most stock allocators will write block data to the page causing it to become somewhat cache-warm by the time you get around to using it, but that may induce a page fault, or push something else out of cache).

Another potential advantage of using the stack is general cache coherence.

```
int i, j, k;
Foo f1, f2, f3;
// ... thousands of operations populating those values
f1.DoCrazyMagic(f1, f2, f3, i, j, k);
```

If there are no external references inside `DoCrazyMagic`, then all operations will happen within a small memory locality. Conversely, if we do

```
int *i, *j, *k;
Foo *f1, *f2, *f3;
// ... thousands of operations populating those values
f1->DoCrazyMagic(*f1, *f2, *f3, *i, *j, *k);
```

It is conceivable that in a complex scenario the variables will be spread out across multiple-pages and may incur multiple page faults.

However - if the "thousands of operations" are intense and complex enough, the stack area where we put `i, j, k, f1, f2 and f3` might no-longer be "hot".

Put another way: If you abuse the stack, it also becomes a contested resource and the advantages over heap usage become marginalized or eliminated.

Comment: +1 just to add - stack is somewhat faster, heap is bigger, deciding between them is usage specific and out of scope

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Good point - any feedback on edit2? [note: I only just saw the 'and out of scope', heh]

Comment: save this post and reuse it when somebody clearly asks the question in a straightforward and easily searchable way

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the two instances is related to object lifetime.

`T1` has dynamic allocation, meaning its lifetime ends when `delete` is called, `T2` has automatic allocation, meaning its lifetime ends when execution leaves the allocation's enclosing block.

Object lifetime should be the primary decision factor when choosing between dynamic or automatic variables.

The second decision factor should be object size. Automatic objects are generally stored on a "stack", which has a limited size. In contrast, dynamically allocated objects can have much larger sizes.

A distant third factor could be locality of reference, which might mean, in some scenarios, that the indirection (`->`) will impose a minute performance penalty. That's something only a profiler can tell.

> I design the methods of T1 and T2 accordingly, meaning that in T1 I
>   pretty much have only void functions that will operate on the this
>   object and inside T2 I will have methods that will access the actual
>   members.

That doesn't really make much sense. Both classes can have members and non-void functions.

Do note that dynamic memory allocations impose a cost and also, usually, a lock must be aquired internally by the memory allocator. You can try different allocators (like [TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) and others) which offer some performance improvements in multithreaded scenarios.

With dynamic storage there is also the real thread of memory leaks, forgetting to call `delete`. This can be alleviated by using smart pointers but they add their own performance penalties.

Overall, the only real issue, in a multithreaded environment or not, is whether you actually need the (lifetime or size) properties offered by dynamic allocation and are willing to pay its performance cost.

(A cost that you should measure before making the decision. Perfect is the enemy of good enough.)

Comment: Locking the memory is only really required if the pointer value is shared across multiple threads, if the allocation, use and deletion all occur in a single thread, then there is no need to lock the memory.